# Gerber lines in ground plane

Tags: eaglecad, ground-plane, gerber

My manufacturer is asking me to remove those lines from the ground gerber layer

[image]

The design was made in eagle, I've been searching information about this problem and I've found nothing, I don't know if it has a specific name or it isn't a real problem

It's a problem of the gerber file?

I'm using Eagle 8.3.0 and GERBER_RS274X as device output

Edit:

[image]

This is the same file exported to a pdf, I've visualized with microsoft edge at100% zoom. When zoom in into 300% the lines are gone

Comment: Did you try to export the file in PDF? Are the lines still here?

Comment: It sounds like you need to change some "hatch" setup when rendering copper poor

Comment: What version of Eagle? What version/type of Gerber?

Comment: @M.Ferru I've printed the file and add the image in the post.

Comment: @AliChen I've selected a solid polygon, but I've the "hatched", could be this be better than solid?

Comment: @TomCarpenter It's Eagle 8.3.0 and gerber_RS274X

Comment: Hmm. Might be something weird with the newer versions - I gave up on V8 and stuck to V6. This seems to be some form of issue with the CAM exporter - it's not something to do with the polygon settings.

Comment: And what gerber viewer? Very fine lines is a pretty common artifact with some viewers, even if the polygon's tracks are lined up just fine.

Comment: Use a Gerber viewer like viewmate it something like it, a PDF or jpg conversion will not show what is actually contained in the Gerber's. The output could be converting the planes to lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this problem.

Well I don't know if I can really call this a solution because I had to switch software.

Before to switch I tried multiples cam files, I exported from Windows and Linux (Ubuntu). I started a [topic](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/eagle-forum/gerber-lines-in-ground-plane/td-p/7374937) in the autodesk forum. Some of the users were able to replicate my problem and others not. <del>The Autodesk representatives were not interested in helping me, so I still don't know what is really happening.</del> They answered but there is not a solution yet (01/2018) (see autodesk topic)

I must say that in Viewmate the problem wasn't present, but my manufacturer wasn't using that software, so wasn't a solution for me. Now with KiCAD the gerber files looks good in any platform or viewer.

My solution was [download KiCAD](http://kicad-pcb.org/download/), at this moment the last version is: 4.0.7, and import the `brd` file.

The steps to open the `brd` file are:

1. open the `pcbnew.exe` file in the `bin` folder located in `C:\Program Files\KiCad\` (I don't know how this works in the others platforms)

You have to do it that way, otherwise you won't have the `open file` option.

2. Go to `File > Open File` and select `XML PCB File from Eagle ver.6.x (*.brd)`

When you select your file it will be imported in KiCAD. In my case I had to make the ground planes (zones) again, but I solved that in less than 5 minutes.

Comment: Might be worth trying an older version of Eagle ([download page on Autodesk site](http://eagle.autodesk.com/eagle/software-versions)). I use 6.6 and have never had such issues. It shouldn't have any major trouble opening newer versions of the .brd/.sch files (you get a note saying some parameter or other is undefined, but it doesn't affect the board/schematic).

Comment: I forgot to mention, I've tried with version 6.0 and it happened same problem. I don't understand where is the problem and I know it can't be a bug affecting all users because no one is asking to fix that. But at least I saved the time spended doing the board, I'm also considerating change my manufacturer

Comment: How odd. Could you upload the board file [here](https://gist.github.com/) and I'll have a try exporting it?

Comment: I've using the esp32 sparkfun board: https://goo.gl/ZDJ8Qp the problem is easy to reproduce with gerbv. In ubuntu it was minor. But with KiCAD the preview was fine in all platform with any software

Answer (score 1):

Put a Width of 0 in the polygon properties.

[image: screenshot]